# Running application throws android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity but using "extends Activity" works

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin

I am stuck with this error and I have no idea how to solve it. I have the following LoginActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    private Button login_btn;
    int attempt_counter = 5;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        LoginButton();
    }

    public void LoginButton() {
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        login_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        login_btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(username.getText().toString().equals("user") &&
                                password.getText().toString().equals("pass")  ) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"User and Password is correct",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(".MainActivity");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"User and Password is not correct",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, im extending "AppCompactActivity". If I run the application, the error mentioned in the subject is thrown. If I update the code and change it to "extends Activity", it works. Why is this happening?

The following is my manifest file, which I'm assuming is correct otherwise the application would never run even when i use "extends activity":

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".MainActivity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

grade file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //implementation "org.apache.poi:poi:3.17"
    //implementation "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.71"
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.0.1'
    //implementation files('libs/poishadow-all.jar')
    //implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    //annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and the stacktrace:

```
2019-02-01 00:02:49.522 18723-18723/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.proj, PID: 18723
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.proj/com.test.proj.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.proj.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.proj-PMMv5uc0Z9RUZsO7uJBe_Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.proj-PMMv5uc0Z9RUZsO7uJBe_Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.proj.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.proj-PMMv5uc0Z9RUZsO7uJBe_Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.proj-PMMv5uc0Z9RUZsO7uJBe_Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                ... 12 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.proj-PMMv5uc0Z9RUZsO7uJBe_Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.proj-PMMv5uc0Z9RUZsO7uJBe_Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                ... 15 more
```

if it helps im also including activity-login.xml, where I commented out some fields because I thought they were causing the compact error, although that wasn't the case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_test_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!-- Email Label -->
        <!--<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginTop="8dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"-->
            <!--android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">-->
            <!--<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/input_email"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:inputType="textEmailAddress"-->
                <!--android:hint="Email" />-->
        <!--</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>-->

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <!--<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginTop="8dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"-->
            <!--android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">-->
            <!--<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/input_password"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:inputType="textPassword"-->
                <!--android:hint="Password"/>-->
        <!--</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>-->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Login"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="No account yet? Create one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EDIT:

added styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Please provide your style/AppTheme source file

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding? It could just be a cache issue.

Comment: I've tried cleaning and rebuilding yes, but the error persists...I'm totally stuck on this error, no idea what else to try. Maybe I should just start all over from scratch..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! Managed to solve it...turns out the culprit was in my gradle file. The following import was causing Android Studio either not to recognise the compact imports or ignore them...

Solution was to remove the following dependency:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.0.1'
```

and instead use the following:

```
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9'
```

Comment: Note: You could keep the syntax the same, and just have changed `version: '4.0.1'` to the other version

Comment: However, I don't know if this way really the "fix". More than likely changing the version caused your app to re-compile, thus fixing other dependencies on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

In the import section, if you can check there is Activity and AppCompactActivity imported. Please remove the activity from the imports rebuild it again and run.

Answer (score 0):

check your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="**Theme.AppCompat**.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

you must use `Theme.AppCompat`